# Passing HTML variable to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying to make damage calculator, where user writes the following variables: Level, military rank, strength and weapon level. But the problem seems i can't to send variables to javascript and the document write doesn't send anything out. Can you check the code and help me?
Regards

```
<form id="form">

Your level:<input type="number" name="level"><br>
Your strength: <input type="number" name="str"><br>
Your military rank: <input type="number" name="mr"> <br>
Your weapon(no weapon=0) <input type="number" name="wep"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">`
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var level = document.getElementById('level').id;
var str = document.getElementById('str').id;
var mr = document.getElementById('mr').id;
var wep = document.getElementById('wep').id;
hit = ((level*4)+str)*(1+(mr/20))*(1+(wep/10));
document.write(hit);
```

Comment: You are using `getElementById`, but none of your elements have IDs. You're then getting `.id` instead of `.value`, and you're wondering why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to get the `id` of the element:

```
document.getElementById('level').id
```

You want to get it's *value*:

```
document.getElementById('level').value
```

Also, in order to use `getElementById`, your element needs to have an `id`:

```
<input type="number" name="level" id="level">
```

Alternatively, without changing the markup, you can use `getElementsByName` and grab the first element in the returned collection:

```
document.getElementsByName('level')[0].value
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are referencing your tag's id, when you never gave it one:

```
Your level:<input type="number" name="level"><br>
```

Should have:

```
Your level:<input type="number" name="level" id="level"><br>
```

Your JS aslo is not asking for the value.  Just the object itelf.  It should be:

```
var level = document.getElementById('level').value
```

Then you're script will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getElementById` but have not defined any Id values.

With the current html markup you can use `getElementsByName()` instead.  The method returns an array of matched elements.

forexample,

```
var str = document.getElementsByName('str')[0].value;
```

Comment: @Popnoodles ah thanks for point that out, had `id` on the brain.